# Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que haga click en el numero salga cualquier letra

Tags: javascript

Quiero que al hacer `click` en el botón me arroje una letra, por ejemplo: si pulsara 7 apareciera `"S"`

```js
var cifra="";
function display_numeros(numero){
  document.getElementById("display").value=cifra+numero;
  cifra=document.getElementById("display").value;
}
```

```css
.numero{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  
  
}

.igual{
  width:120px;
  height:60px;
  
}

table{
  margin:auto;
}

.color_display{
  height:30px;
  background-color:#000;
  border:medium #FFF;
  font: "Space Age";
  color:#0F0;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:right;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table width="15%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
    <input name="display" type="text" class="color_display" id="display" size="25"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="num7" type="submit" class="numero" id="num7" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input name="num8" type="submit" class="numero" id="num8" value="8" ></td>
    <td><input name="num9" type="submit" class="numero" id="num9" value="9" ></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí quiere que al dar `click` en el botón se genere una letra aleatoriamente, podría tener un `array` o `String` de las letras posibles, y luego aplicar un `Random` para obtener el indice de la letra elegida. Una vez obtenido el indice usar el método [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charAt)  *(si desea letras mayúsculas u otros caracteres , agregarlos al String)*

```js
//posibles letras a elegir
var letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
// Seleccionamos el input de salida para mostrar la letra
var inputresult= document.getElementById("display");
//Obtenemos los botones con la clase numero
var botones = document.querySelectorAll('.numero');
// iteramos sobre los botones
botones.forEach(function(el){
  // agregamos el listener para el evento click
  el.addEventListener('click',function(){
    // si se da click, asignamos la letra random obtenida
    //´por medio de charAt
    inputresult.value = letras.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letras.length));
  });
});
```

```html
<table width="15%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
    <input name="display" type="text" class="color_display" id="display" size="25"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="num7" type="submit" class="numero" id="num7" value="7" ></td>
    <td><input name="num8" type="submit" class="numero" id="num8" value="8" ></td>
    <td><input name="num9" type="submit" class="numero" id="num9" value="9" ></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no pones en ninguna parte del código que al hacer click en el botón se ejecute la función `display_numeros`.

Los botones, si están en un formulario, ta y como los tienes enviarán el formulario, por lo que en `type` es mejor que pongas `button`.

Prueba con el código siguiente que es el tuyo con un par de modificaciones:

```js
var cifra="";
function display_numeros(numero){
  document.getElementById("display").value=cifra+numero;
  cifra=document.getElementById("display").value;
}
```

```css
.numero{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  
  
}

.igual{
  width:120px;
  height:60px;
  
}

table{
  margin:auto;
}

.color_display{
  height:30px;
  background-color:#000;
  border:medium #FFF;
  font: "Space Age";
  color:#0F0;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:right;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
 
<table width="15%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
    <input name="display" type="text" class="color_display" id="display" size="25"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="num7" type="button" class="numero" id="num7" value="7" onClick="display_numeros(7)"></td>
    <td><input name="num8" type="button" class="numero" id="num8" value="8" onClick="display_numeros(8)"></td>
    <td><input name="num9" type="button" class="numero" id="num9" value="9" onClick="display_numeros(9)"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Los `<input>` que envían un formulario son los que tienen  `submit` como valor de `type`. Los de `button` por sí solos no hacen nada.

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias formas para que un botón realice una acción al hacer clic en él.

- Incluir el atributo onClick teniendo como valor el código JavaScript a ejecutar. Este código puede ser una llamada a una función o puede ser directamente la instrucción.

  Ejemplo:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="txt">
    </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="7" onClick="getElementById('txt').value='S';">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- Usar un "listener". El segundo parámetro debe ser un objeto, el cual puede ser una llamada o una función.

  Ejemplo:

```js
document
  .getElementById('btn')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value = 'S';
  })
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="txt">
    </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```